# Find the largest square that can fit within a given polygon centered a a given point

Tags: geometry, polygon

Let's say I have a polygon specified by a set of vertices.

In addition, I also have a defined "starting point" that could be anywhere in the polygon.

How could I find the largest square, centered at the starting point, that fits completely within the polygon?

Comment: a drawing would help

Comment: Is rotation allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust For my purposes, no.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the largest x,y aligned distances from vertices to the start point?

If you also consider the sign of the distance you get the maximun +x,-x size and +y,-y size

Answer (score 0):

The size of the square is limited by either one of its sides hitting a vertex of the polygon or one of its corners hitting a side of the polygon.

If rotation is not allowed,

- find the shortest horizontal or vertical distance from the target point to the vertices;
- find the closest intersections of the main bissectors through the target point and the polygon outline.

Keep the smallest square so defined.

If rotation is allowed, the problem is more difficult.